# Как в адаптере recyclerView открывать данные из списка в новой активности?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-intent, recyclerview.adapter

Есть список recyclerView, данные в который добавляются из базы данных, как сделать так, чтобы при щелчке по одному из пунктов в списке, текст этого пункта открывался в новой активности?

Ниже представлен код адаптера, в котором я пытаюсь осуществить эту передачу данных:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

            TextView tvOut;

            private List<TextRow> mDataset;

            // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
            // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
            // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
            public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                // each data item is just a string in this case
                public TextView textView;
                public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
                    super(v);
                    textView = v;

                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //здесь я 
    //безуспешно пытаюсь передать данные из списка в другую активность

                         @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int positionIndex = getAdapterPosition();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadText.class); 

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            public MyAdapter(List<TextRow> myDataset) {
                mDataset = myDataset;
            }

            // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
            @Override
            public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {
                // create a new view
                TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);

                MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);


                return vh;


            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                // - get element from your dataset at this position
                // - replace the contents of the view with that element
                holder.textView.setText(mDataset.get(position).name);


            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mDataset.size();
            }
        }
```

P.S. Если нужен код активности, для которой предназначен этот адаптер и базы данных, их тоже могу добавить

Comment: во вторую активность передавать id кликнутой записи и по этому id во второй активности читать из БД всю нужную информацию

Answer (score 1):

Не советую делать `startActivity()` в адаптере, лучше сделать это в `Activity` или `Fragment`. Я так делаю, но это с java 8

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

     private Consumer<TextRow> listener;

     public MyAdapter(Consumer<TextRow> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
     }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
          holder.itemView.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
              listener.accept(mDataset.get(position))
          });
      }
  ......
 }


 class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...........
     void setupRecyclerView() {
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(::onClick);
        ............
     }

    void onClick(TextRow texrow) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putSerializable("key_textrow", textrow)
        startActivity(intent);
    }

 }
```

ну или вместо `Consumer<TextRow>` можно создать собственный интерфейс `OnClickListener`с медотом `onTextRowClick(TextRow textrow)` в `MyAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Кто как, конечно, но обычно такие вещи делаются при помощи интерфейсов. 
View.OnClickListener  это тоже интерфейс, но можно создать и свой прикрев нужную логику.
Вот пример простой реализации:

Создаете свой интерфейс:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {

void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

потом делаете его реализацию в адаптере RecyclerView

В адаптере:

```
 private static OnItemClickListener listener;

void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    Adapter.listener = listener;
}
```

а во ViewHoldere цепляете на нужную View:

```
item_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (Adapter.listener != null)
                        Adapter.listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
     }
```

Ну а во фрагменте или активности просто имплементите его:

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener.OnFinanceItemClickListener
```

Не забываем про `adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitySecond.class);
        intent.putExtra(MyConstants.POSITION, position);           
       startActivity(intent);            
        }
    }
```

Вот и все.